# C# MongoDB & Projection. Fails with serialization Exception

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, projection

Let's say I have a collection like :

```
 {
 id: "1"
 name: "collection 1"
 properties: "Some properties."
 }
```

With a class representation as

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class InfoPOCO {
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("properties")]
    public string Properties { get; set; }
 }
```

Now if am going to create a Projection like

```
Builders<InfoPOCO>.Projection.Include(_ => new{_.Name});
```

And call it with other params ( That is working fine without projection )

```
return GetDataBase().GetCollection<InfoPOCO>(collectionName).Find(Expr).
Project<InfoPOCO>(projectionDefinition).Skip(Offset).Limit(Limit).Sort(sort).ToList<InfoPOCO>()
```

Then I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to determine the serialization information for
_ => new <>f__AnonymousType2`1


 Result StackTrace: 
at MongoDB.Driver.ExpressionFieldDefinition`1.Render(IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.SingleFieldProjectionDefinition`1.Render(IBsonSerializer`1 sourceSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.KnownResultTypeProjectionDefinitionAdapter`2.Render(IBsonSerializer`1 sourceSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.CreateFindOperation[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindSync[TProjection](IClientSessionHandle session, FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<>c__DisplayClass35_0`1.<FindSync>b__0(IClientSessionHandle session)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSession[TResult](Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindSync[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.FindFluent`2.ToCursor(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.ToList[TDocument](IAsyncCursorSource`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

What could be the reason for it, when am not using projection, it is fetching the entire collection fine. I don't know if I need to map the classes? (Thought Auto Map would take it) . I tried making the constructor in the class too. But still the same error. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: Did you actually type in `Builders<T>`? The `T` is meant to be your actual class type.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that is generics, I have stripped down the question to be included in here, let me edit out the T to avoid confusion.

Comment: I think you need to be "anonymous type" implies that you put something wrong in there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, tried that too, still the same error mate. And the code works fine without any projection.

Comment: Show the class definition. Also try something other than `_` like `p` or a standard alphabetical identifier.

Comment: Added the information and tried with P instead of _ too. Still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood! Yeah, I know, kinda slow, duh.

The issue is that when I was trying to map it like :

```
Builders<InfoPOCO>.Projection.Include(_ => new{_.Name, _.Properties});
```

It's a strongly typed expression and the result is mapped to an anonymous type. If am using forEach at the same time as am fetching it, then I can get those values. So the solution I am using right now is simple. I changed my projection to:

```
Builders<InfoPOCO>.Projection.Include(_ => _.Name).
                              Include(_ => _.Properties);
```

This works! Am not saying its the perfect solution or explanation but I see a lot of people struggling with it, so just mentioning a workaround. Hope it helps someone like me from going through hours of googling!